# Properly placing chunk split in PHP

Tags: php

I have a snippet of WP/PHP code and the below outputs this: 20150204

```
<?php echo  $datef=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_slot', true); ?>
```

I want to use chunk split and split the date with a forward slash: 2015/02/04

Tried a few methods but it's not as simple as doing a normal chunk split with a normal string, as I want it to appear, 4/2/2. So far I have this:

```
<?php $datef=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_slot', true); 
echo chunk_split($datef,4, '/') ?>
```

Which is outputting this: 2015/0204/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_slot', true));
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$dateValue = '20150204';
$time=strtotime($dateValue);
$year=date("Y",$time);
$month=date("m",$time);
$day=date("d",$time);
echo $year."/".$month."/".$day;  //Output : 2015/02/04
```

Comment: @Owen O'Neill : this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

chunk_split() seems like the wrong tool since it is designed to split a string into chunks of the same size - but your date has two different sizes (4, 2, 2).

Since you are working with dates, the logical place to look are date functions. The DateTime (PHP 5.3+) class has a method createFromFormat()  which allows you to covert your date string into a logical date object which then can be worked with, including formatting with the format() method.